# Amazon WorkMail - forward every email

Tags: email, forward, amazon-workmail

I have read over 20 different guides, most of which hosted by Amazon, and every guide is either out of date or simply does not work.

We have a support email, support@blah.com

All I am trying to do is **forward EVERY email sent to support@ to our other emails** (ie bob@blah.com, tim@blah.com, etc)

I have achieved this but it doesn't always work AND some of the emails forward with the information on who it *was* going to send to but others return JUST the email and I do not understand why I am getting two different types of forwards.

I have set up these four "email rules" in Amazon Workmail:

*IF "is sent only to me" -> forward the message to X

*IF "includes these words in sender's address" keyword is: [;] -> forward msg

*IF "includes these words in the sender's address" keyword is: [@] -> forward msg

*IF "is received from" and email is: support@blah (which is the email I am logged in as, so if it's sent to "myself") -> forward msg

All rules are marked as "active" and all rules are marked as "stop processing rules after this rule is applied"

Under these four rules we get most emails but not all sent to support@.
Plus, like I said, we get two different versions of our forward.

1) "good version" - which includes who it was suppose to be sent to (this is what I want every email to look like) [see good email]

2) "bad version" - which only has the actual content of the email and not who it was sent to [see bad email)

The sending of the email is no different so it has to be WorkMail's forwarding rules that are determining to show or not show the forward information- or so I'm guessing?

[good email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgqKe.png)

[bad email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGZdW.png)

Comment: Ok here is what has given me the most reliable redirecting:

`I removed the 4 rules above` and replaced them with:
`IF "includes these words in the sender's address" keywords: [entered in every letter of the alphabet as well as the symbols + numbers]`
AND
`IF "include these words in the subject or body" keywords: [same thing, I added every letter and number]`
Using those two new rules I was able to get more reliable email triggers to fire (although some still missed).

**I also changed the action from forward to: _redirect the message_**

Comment: This is ridiculous. I ended up using `IF "includes these words in the sender's address" keywords: [every letter + numbers]` and it seems to work (every e-mail address should at least have a letter or number). How can such a basic feature be completely broken in WorkMail?

Answer (score 26):

There is a quite simple workaround.

1. Go to `Settings` -> `Email Rules` -> `New`
2. Define a name for the rule ("Forward All" seems logic)
3. Select `Active Rule`
4. Go to `Conditions` and select **Includes these words in the sender’s address** from de drop-down.
5. Click on "Select words" and write `@`, click `Add` button and finally the `Ok` button.
6. Go to `Actions` and select **Forward the message to** and the desired email address.
7. Click `Ok` in the main modal and finally click `Save changes`.

With this single rule, every single email will be redirected because every sender's address will have `@`.

Comment: One note on this - there's a difference between "forwarding" and "redirecting" messages. Apparently "forwarding" from support@mydomain to otheraccount@mydomain means that your replies from the otheraccount@mydomain will go to support@mydomain, not to the original sender. If you want your replies to go to the original sender, follow the above instructions but choose "redirect" instead of "forward".

Comment: i tried this solution, it seems like it is not working. Whether as foward or redirect. Can someone confirm this is not working ?

Comment: I'm using redirect, works perfect!

Comment: It's Juli 2023, and I can confirm that redirect is nicer than forward, as not every email subject gets a “FW:” prepended. Also, `@` did not work reliable for me, „includes these words in the message header...“ and then taking my „familyname“ as the word (which is the domain I associated with aws, and from which I want to redirect everything elsewhere, so it certainly is in there…) does work well.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be much easier to remove the "support@" user account and create a group with the "support@" email address.  Then add all the users that you want to receive the support emails, as members of the group?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please edit and rephrase this into a more assertive answer. At present it runs the risk of being deleted if reviewers believe it to be a question, rather than an answer.